# How to de-duplicate a lookup table based on two parent ids

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a lookup table with three columns: child_id, parent_id and master_parent_id. I'm using R and I want to de-duplicate the children ids based on the combined info of the two other parent ids.

Example:

```
df = structure(list(child_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                                     12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), 
                        parent_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
                                      3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
                        master_parent_id = c(1, 
                                             1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, NA, NA, NA)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -18L), 
                   spec = structure(list(cols = list(child_id = structure(
                     list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), 
                     parent_id = structure(list(), 
                                           class = c("collector_double", 
                                                     "collector")), 
                     master_parent_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                    "collector"))), 
                     default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                           "collector")), delim = ","), 
                     class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
    
df

    # A tibble: 18 × 3
       child_id parent_id master_parent_id
          <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
     1        1         1                1
     2        2         1                1
     3        3         2                2
     4        4         2                2
     5        5         3                2
     6        6         3                2
     7        7         3                2
     8        8         3                2
     9        9         3                2
    10       10         3                3
    11       11         4                4
    12       12         5                5
    13       13         6                6
    14       14         7                7
    15       15         7                8
    16       16         8               NA
    17       17         9               NA
    18       18        10               NA
```

As you can see in the example table above, some of the child records can be deduped by the parent_id alone, some others by master_parent_id alone and some others by the combination of the two. I want the final id to dedupe based on their combined info. The master_parent_lookup should have "priority" (use this one wherever possible, however, it can be NA). The final_id doesn't have to be a number, you can create a character if it's easier.

The final output needs to look like this:

```
final_table
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   child_id parent_id master_parent_id final_id
      <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        1         1                1        1
 2        2         1                1        1
 3        3         2                2        2
 4        4         2                2        2
 5        5         3                2        2
 6        6         3                2        2
 7        7         3                2        2
 8        8         3                2        2
 9        9         3                2        2
10       10         3                3        2
11       11         4                4        4
12       12         5                5        5
13       13         6                6        6
14       14         7                7        7
15       15         7                8        7
16       16         8               NA        7
17       17         9               NA        9
18       18        10               NA        10
```

Comment: Why is row 10 2 and not 3?

Comment: @Maël because parent_id: 3 is the same as master_parent_id:2 according to the previous rows

Comment: Woops! That was a typo, thanks :) This is now fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `igraph` approach:

```r
m <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(master_parent_id = coalesce(master_parent_id, parent_id)) %>% 
  select(from = parent_id, to = master_parent_id) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  components() %>% 
  pluck(membership)

df %>% 
  mutate(final_id = m[parent_id])
```

Output

```r
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   child_id parent_id master_parent_id final_id
      <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        1         1                1        1
 2        2         1                1        1
 3        3         2                2        2
 4        4         2                2        2
 5        5         3                2        2
 6        6         3                2        2
 7        7         3                2        2
 8        8         3                2        2
 9        9         3                2        2
10       10         3                3        2
11       11         4                4        3
12       12         5                5        4
13       13         6                6        5
14       14         7                7        6
15       15         7                8        6
16       16         8               NA        6
17       17         9               NA        7
18       18        10               NA        8
```